# Why $E[d^TMd] = tr(\Sigma M)+tr(\mu\mu^T M)$ if $d$ is normal $(\mu,\Sigma)$?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, expectation

I am trying to derive the equation below,

$E[d^TMd] = tr(\Sigma M)+tr(uu^T M)$

where $d \sim \phi(\mu,\Sigma) $,

$\phi()$ is Gaussian distribution,

M is a n by n matrix, and d is a n by 1 vector.

since $d^TMd$ is a scalar, trace($d^TMd$) = trace($dd^TM$)

so, $E[d^TMd] = E[tr(d^TMd)] = E[tr(d d^T M)] $

and I am stuck.

Comment: You did not use the hypothesis "where $d \sim \phi(\mu,\Sigma)$" yet. Time to do exactly that!

Comment: I can't figure out a way to use it, it just seems to me d should be broken down, but I am not sure what property is needed here.

Comment: Say $\mu=0$, then what would be $E(dd^T)$?

Comment: Note that expectation is linear and $\mathbb{E}(d d^{\mathrm{t}}) = \Sigma + \mu \mu^{\mathrm{t}}$.

Comment: @WimC why is that?

Comment: Sorry but what do you know about normal joint distributions if this does not include $E(dd^T)$ when $d$ is normal centered?

Comment: I know that expectation is a linear operator, and M is a constant that can be taken out of expectation, $dd^T$ is a symmetric matrix.

Comment: Thus, *nothing about normal distributions*? Seems we are back at my first comment since, as long as you avoid to use normality, you will make no progress towards a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think know how $E[dd^T]=\Sigma+\mu\mu^T$ is derived, then it's just

$E[tr(dd^TM)] = \\ 
tr(E[dd^TM]) =\\
tr(E[dd^T]M) =\\
tr((\Sigma + \mu\mu^T)M) = \\
tr(\Sigma M + \mu\mu^T M) = \\
tr(\Sigma M) + tr(\mu\mu^TM)$